# Push to newly created branch in git

Tags: git, github

I am working on a branch, 'development'. On Github, I created a new branch called 'Temporary'. I want to push my current code to branch temporary.

In my workspace doing

```
git branch
```

gives * development
        master

On trying,

```
git push origin temporary
```

I get: src refspec temporary does not match any

The git show-ref doesn't show the branch either

What can I do to push to the new branch temporary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about Git's workflow.  Typically, there are two possible scenarios here.  The first is that you *pull* the `temporary` branch on GitHub to your local machine.  You would then do some work and eventually sync up with GitHub by doing a `git push origin temporary`.  The second scenario is that you create a local branch on your machine called `temporary`.  You could do this from the `master` branch by doing `git branch temporary`.  You would then *push* this branch to GitHub using `git push origin temporary`.

If you are certain that you really want to push the `master` branch to the `temporary` branch on GitHub, then you can force it by doing `git push origin temporary --force`

From your later comments, this is what you want to do:

```
git checkout master
# work work work
git checkout -b temporary
git push origin temporary
```

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I pulled the development branch. I worked on it and made some changes. Now I want to push the changes. Not to the development branch, but a different temporary branch that I created.

Comment: `git checkout -b temporary` followed by `git push origin temporary`  You _don't_ create the branch on GitHub first...you create on it on your local machine and then push it to GitHub.  Read my answer carefully.

Comment: Thanks. When I created the branch locally, I am still stuck on development as my current branch, even though it shows temporary. How do  I move to the Temporary branch locally?

Comment: `git checkout temporary`

Comment: `git checkout Temporary` will switch to the branch, or if you are on `master` you could do `git checkout -b Temporary` to create the new branch _and_ switch to it at the same time.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Though now I am getting a fast-forward error

Comment: This means that the branch on GitHub has changes since you last pulled and your local branch has diverged.  You can pull or rebase those changes in and then commit.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a branch locally and checkout to that new branch

```
git checkout -b temporary
```

Make all changes, commit your code and then do this

```
git push origin temporary
```

Comment: And are you currently on `temporary` branch?

Comment: No. While I was working on the development branch, I created the temporary brach on Github

Comment: Then you will have to pull that branch first